# sql join, get all info from one table and count from another

Tags: sql-server

i have 3 table and need to count how many times a type appears in the booking table, and also show the other types as a count of zero if they dont appear. 
my sql looks like this, but it is only giving me the type that apears in the booking table.

```
 SELECT        Types.Type, COUNT(Types.Type) AS Total
FROM            Booking INNER JOIN
                     Pitch ON Booking.Location_id = Pitch.Location_Id INNER JOIN
                     Types ON Pitch.Type_ID = Types.Type_ID
 WHERE        (MONTH(Booking.EndDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()) ) OR
                     (MONTH(Booking.StartDate) = MONTH(GETDATE()))
  GROUP BY Types.Type
```

the three tables are Booking,Pitch,Type
booking has Location_id, pitch has Location_id, and Type_ID, and Type has Type_ID

Any Ideas

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: zedfoxus -  Look at my answer below please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
Types.Type,
(SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM Pitch
            LEFT JOIN booking ON Pitch.Location_Id = booking.Location_Id
    WHERE Pitch.Type_ID = Types.Type_ID
            AND ( MONTH(Booking.EndDate) = month(GETDATE()) OR MONTH(Booking.StartDate) = month(GETDATE()) )
    ) AS total
From Types
```

Comment: that works a charm, thank you, next is to get one statement for this month, one for last month, and one for next month,  i can get them all individually but getting it on one table, i need to have a look at ??

Answer (score 0):

```
select types.type, COUNT(Booking.Location_id) AS "Total"
FROM   Pitch LEFT JOIN
         Booking
 ON Pitch.Location_Id = Booking.Location_id
 LEFT JOIN Types ON Pitch.Type_ID=Types.Type_ID
GROUP BY types.type
```

This gives me the info i need for all the booking table, i then want to filter it to show only bookings from this month.
ive tried this

```
 select types.type, COUNT(Booking.Location_id) AS "Total"
 FROM   Pitch LEFT JOIN
         Booking
 ON Pitch.Location_Id = Booking.Location_id
 LEFT JOIN Types ON Pitch.Type_ID=Types.Type_ID
 where
 month(Booking.EndDate) = month(GETDATE())

 or month(Booking.StartDate) = month(GETDATE())
 GROUP BY types.type
```

but this again only gives the one type that has been booked this month

with the top query i get a table like this

```
  _______________
 |TYPES   |  TOTAL|
 | DELUX  |  1    |
 | STANDARD| 3    |
 | WILD   |  0    |
 | SUPER  |  0    |
```

but with the filer i get just Delux as its the only one with the start/end date in this month i am expecting

```
       _______________
       |TYPES   |  TOTAL|
       | DELUX  |  1    |
       | STANDARD| 0    |
       | WILD   |  0    |
       | SUPER  |  0    |
```

Comment: Does this mean you have answered your own question? Or do you need any further help?

Comment: Let's take one step at a time. Does your first query output correct results (where delux is 1, standard is 3, wild is 0 and super is 0)?